# Black-Scholes to Diffusion Initial Condition

Tags: black-scholes, differential-equations

I'm having troubles with the transformation from the Black-Scholes PDE and transforming it to the diffusion equation.  I read this other stackexchange post ([Here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/84/transformation-from-the-black-scholes-differential-equation-to-the-diffusion-equ)) and I understand most of the process, except where they changed the initial condition.

I got
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
u(x,0) &= e^{r\tau}C(S,T)\\
&=e^{r\tau}\text{max}(S-K,0)\\
&=e^{r\tau}\text{max}(e^y-K,0)\\
&=e^{r\tau}\text{max}(e^{x-(r-\sigma^2/2)\tau)}-K,0)\\
&=\text{max}(e^{x+\sigma^2\tau/2}-e^{r\tau}K,0)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Which is different from their equation of:
\begin{equation}
u(x,0) = u_0(x) = \text{max}(e^{\frac{1}{2}(a+1)x}-e^{\frac{1}{2}(a-1)x},0)
\end{equation}

Where $a=2r/\sigma^2$

I would comment on the other post, however I don't have enough 'reputation' and this is a very specific question that I can't find elsewhere.  Apparently it's in the textbook referenced in the original post, but the particular page referenced isn't freely available.

Comment: In Dewynne's et al.  derivation, there is an extra step (involving going from "v" to "u") that is not shown in the stackexchange post you linked...

Answer (score 1):

$$u(x,0)=e^{\frac{k-1}{2}x}v(x,0)$$

and $$v(x,0)=max(e^{x}-1,0)$$ 
Hence 
 $$u(x,0)=max(e^{\frac{k+1}{2}x}-e^{\frac{k-1}{2}x},0)$$