# Black-Scholes equation to Heat equation .(Boundary conditions)

Tags: black-scholes, black-scholes-pde, parabolic-pde, black-scholes-merton

I have been given a problem to code the heat equation which is transformed from B-S equation (European call option) .

Now the boundary conditions are for European call option: 
$$C(S,T)=\max(S-K,0)$$ 
$$C(0,t)=0$$ 
$$C(S,t) \sim S \space  as \> S\to \infty$$
Transforming it to heat equation :$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} $$
with the initial condition: 
$$u(x,0)=max(e^{\frac{k+1}{2}x}-e^{\frac{k-1}{2}x},0)$$
what are the boundary conditions for this heat equation ?

Comment: Apply the same transformation that you used to get the initial condition from the payoff function to get the transformed boundary conditions from the original ones.

Comment: The first boundary condition is $0$. I am confused about the second one.

Comment: @LocalVolatility , do you have any link to any such paper related to my question? I am stuck.

Comment: Please add the exact change of variables you used to get from $C(S, t)$ to $u(x, \tau)$ and what your desired boundary conditions on $C(S, t)$ are, then I'll answer the question.

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/84/transformation-from-the-black-scholes-differential-equation-to-the-diffusion-equ

here the derivation was given. they used the same parameters but  the boundary conditions of the heat equation is not given. 
I get weird boundary conditions.

Comment: @LocalVolatility , I have gone through the book that was given in that thread and looked into quite a few solutions. I did not see anywhere the transformed boundary conditions

Comment: @user1157 in link you gave for the derivation, it is described the function $u= e^{r \tau}C$ and decided on a change of variables $x=y+\tau(r−\frac{σ^2}{2}) $