# Is it possible to transform arithmetic-average strike continuous sampling Asian Black-Scholes equation to a heat equation?

Tags: black-scholes, black-scholes-pde, asian-option

By [Transformation from the Black-Scholes differential equation to the diffusion equation - and back](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/84/transformation-from-the-black-scholes-differential-equation-to-the-diffusion-equ), we are able to transform vanilla European option into a heat equation.

And we know that the arithmetic-average strike continuous sampling Asian Black-Scholes equation is 
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}  +\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial ^2 V}{\partial S^2}  +rS\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + S\frac{\partial V}{\partial J}- rV=0$$
i.e., only one more term $S\frac{\partial V}{\partial J}$ compared with original BS equation.

Since this equation is similar to the original BS equation, I assume that we can transform it into a heat equation. Am I correct?

Comment: What is $S\frac{\partial V}{\partial J}$ doing here? What is the partial derivate of V wrt to J? Moreover, where is J coming from?

Comment: @DavidAddison I think what the OP means with J is $$J = \int_0^t S_u du$$ where $t$ is current valuation date and the contract inception is at time $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. On face value, I don't think it will transform into the heat equation because if it could, someone would've already done it, thereby solving the century old problem of the sums/averages of lognormals. But that's not a strong argument.

A few notes:

- Regular Brownian Motion is normally distributed. The sums/averages of normal distributions are normally distributed.
- Geometric Brownian Motion is lognormally distributed. The sums/averages of lognormals are not lognormally distributed.
- Rather, the sums (or equally, the arithmetic averages) of lognormally distributed variables is believed to result in a Bessel process - known as the Integrated Geometric Brownian Motion (wrt time) - that converges to an inverse gamma distribution. This has been studied extensively ([Yor and Geman. Bessel Processes, Asian Options, and Perpetuities. 1993](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-56634-9_6)) ([Daniel Dufresne. Sums of Lognormals. 200](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/38a3/9907d5af01a6340c3b6f38dce39be3be5e8a.pdf))([Daniel Dufresne, Bessel Processes and Asian Options. 2005](http://ozdaniel.com/A/DufresneBessel2005.pdf)) However, no known analytic transformation exists for deriving the parameters of this distribution. Rather, they are typically evaluated using numerical methods or approximations.
- Many approximations (e.g., Fenton-Wilkinson moment matching method) rely on the observation that the sums/average of lognormal distributions resemble a lognormal distribution.
- The exception to the above applies when taking the **unconditional** expectation of the time integral since randomness is non-consequential to the expected value (needed for risk neutral assumption regardless).

Intuitively, the extra term $S\frac{\partial V}{\partial J}$ is responsible for convexity errors terms which are analogous to Jensen's inequality. Ito's lemma is able to account for these errors by adding the term $\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t$ to GBM. The issue, though, is finding a transformation of variables a known distribution. This will probably be solved sometime in my lifetime.