# B-S derivative with another boundary condition

Tags: options, black-scholes, differential-equations, jump-diffusion

I want to use the derivation of BS for another type of derivative, not an option. Known the derivation of the Black-Scholes differential equation, is it possible to use in the same equation when my boundary condition changes and now it's a free boundary?

Here is the equation of BS from the book:
[Transformation from the Black-Scholes differential equation to the diffusion equation - and back](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/84/transformation-from-the-black-scholes-differential-equation-to-the-diffusion-equ)

My question:
If the derivative is:

$$G \left(S,t\right)=\begin{cases}
s_{b}-S_{t} & 0\le S_{t}\le s_{b}\\
S_{t}-s_{b} & s_{b}<S_{t},\,S_{t}\ngeq s_{a}\\
s_{a}-S_{t} & S_{t}<s_{a},\,S_{t}\nleq s_{b}\\
S_{t}-s_{a} & s_{a}<S_{t}<\infty
\end{cases}$$

$$\Downarrow$$ $$G\left(S,t\right)=\begin{cases}
\text{PT}\left(S,s_{b}\right) & 0\le S_{t}\le s_{b}\\
S_{t}-s_{b} & s_{b}<S_{t},\,S_{t}\ngeq s_{a}\\
s_{a}-S_{t} & S_{t}<s_{a},\,S_{t}\nleq s_{b}\\
\text{CL}\left(S,s_{a}\right) & s_{a}<S_{t}<\infty
\end{cases}$$

How was look equation 5.8 in ["The mathematics of financial derivative"](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511812545) p.88

Comment: Maybe you could specify what equation 5.8 is?